# Elementary set theory Exercise

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ ,$ B$  and $ C $ be three parts of a set E such that: $ B ⊂ A ⊂ C $

Determine the set $X ⊂ E $ knowing that:

$A \cap X = B$ and  $A \cup X = C $

I tried to prove that **$X = (C ∩ \overline A) ∪ B$**:

$A ∪ X= C ⇒ (A ∪ X) ∩ \overline A = C ∩  \overline A ⇒ X ∩  \overline A = C ∩  \overline A $

$⇒ (C ∩  \overline A) ∪ B= (X ∩  \overline A) ∪ B = (B ∪ X) ∩ ( \overline A ∪ B)= X ∩ ( \overline A ∪ B) $(since $B  ⊂ X$)

Let's  prove that$ X ⊂ ( \overline A∪ B)$:

$A ∩ X = B ⇒ (A ∩ X) ∪  \overline A = B ∪  \overline A ⇒ X ∪  \overline A = B ∪  \overline A ⇒  X ⊂ ( \overline A∪ B)$

Therefore$ (C ∩  \overline A) ∪ B= X$

My question is:

First of all, have I committed any mistakes?

Second of all, Is there any solution we can write  without using Venn diagram?( Because I've used it beforehand to know that $X = (C ∩ Ac) ∪ B) $) if so, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks good to me. What do you mean by "without using Venn diagrams"? I notice that you haven't used any... By the way, you can put math between dollar signs, and use \cup for union, and \cap for intersection.

Comment: Thank you for the information, No I have drawn one and used it to have an idea about X: I remarked that X can be written as (C ∩ Ac) ∪ B), then I tried to prove it. But what I wanted is to determine the set X, based only on  the two equalities, without any prior idea.

Comment: As Brian points out in his answer, there's nothing wrong with using Venn diagrams to see what's going on. In fact a lot of mathematics is done by using simplified and inaccurate pictures to understand what's going on, before doing the formal work. It looks like you've done exactly that!

Comment: Yes, I know that but I just wanted a solution like what Brian did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with using a Venn diagram to see what’s going on. However, you *can* avoid it here if you notice that

- $A\cap X=B$ implies that $B\subseteq X$ and $X\cap(A\setminus B)=\varnothing$, and
- $A\cup X=C$ implies that $X\subseteq C$ and $X\supseteq C\setminus A$.

Since $B\subseteq A\subseteq C$, $C$ can be partitioned into $B$, $A\setminus B$, and $C\setminus A$. $X$ is a subset of $C$ that contains the first and last of these pieces and is disjoint from the second, so it must be exactly the union of the first and last pieces: $X=B\cup(C\setminus A)$.

Your proof is also fine. You could also use a point-chasing argument, which is often easier. Suppose that $x\in X$; then $x\in C$, since $A\cup X=C$ and therefore $X\subseteq C$. Now either $x\in A$, or $x\notin A$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in B$, since $A\cap X=B$. If $x\notin A$, then $x\in C\setminus A$. In either case $x\in B\cup(C\setminus A)$, so $X\subseteq B\cup(C\setminus A)$.

Now suppose that $x\in B\cup(C\setminus A)$, so that $x\in B$ or $x\in C\setminus A$. $A\cap X=B$, so $B\subseteq X$, and therefore $x\in B$ implies that $x\in X$. If, on the other hand, $x\in C\setminus A$, then $$x\in(A\cup X)\setminus A=X\setminus A\subseteq X\;,$$ so again $x\in X$, and we’ve shown that $B\cup(C\setminus A)\subseteq X$ and hence that $X=B\cup(C\setminus A)$.